# Verify reCaptcha V2 : Always false

Tags: php, wordpress, captcha, verification

I'm trying to implant reCaptcha V2 of Google in my website (developed in PHP & Wordpress).

I'm trying to verify if the user has checked this Captcha before the submit.

And here is my verification :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
  $privatekey = $secret;
  $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
  $data = array(
      'secret' => $privatekey,
      'response' => $captcha,
      'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
  );

  $curlConfig = array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_POST => true,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
  );

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $jsonResponse = json_decode($response);
  if ($jsonResponse->success == true) {
            $succMsg = 'Your contact request have submitted successfully.';
            echo "<script>alert(\"OK\")</script>";
  }
  else {
      $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
            echo "<script>alert(\"KO ROBOT\")</script>";
    }
}
else{

  $errMsg = 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.';
    echo "<script>alert(\"KO CLICK ON BOX\")</script>";
}
?>
```

When I reload the page, or when I submit without checked captcha, or when I checked captcha, it always displays:`"KO ROBOT"`

I have tried also with `"file_get_contents"` instead of curl, but I had an SSL error Warning.

Thanks.

UPDATE :

When i do this :

```
var_dump($jsonResponse);
```

I have this on my page :

> object(stdClass)#4028 (2) { ["success"]=> bool(false)
>   ["error-codes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "invalid-input-secret" }
>   }

UPDATE 2 :

Now i have this, after verification of my secret key :

> object(stdClass)#4028 (2) { ["success"]=> bool(false)
>   ["error-codes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "timeout-or-duplicate" }
>   }

Comment: `var_dump($jsonResponse);` - you should see the error there.

Comment: why u are re verifying? if `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` is persent then its not robot else robot

Comment: Value of $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] can be faked.

Comment: Hey @Mr.Blue , i have this with a var_dump :
 object(stdClass)#4028 (2) { ["success"]=> bool(false) ["error-codes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "invalid-input-secret" } }

Comment: can you update it on your question

Comment: Use the correct `secret key` if that is the case. Also use the correct `site key` in your form.

Comment: from the response looks like you using incorrect secret key

Comment: may be testing capcha with BOT :)

Comment: I'm using the right secret key..

Comment: What about the `site key` in your form?

Comment: Look at my updates @Mr.Blue , i have forgot a character in my private key, i have another error message now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try with this one, just replace secret key.

```
<?php
$response   = isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) ? $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] : null;
$privatekey = "YOUR PRIVATE KEY";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'secret' => $privatekey,
    'response' => $response,
    'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
));

$resp = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);

if ($resp->success) {

} else {

    //failed return mess
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks brother, you have a good answer. Now it works, thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you maybe explain your answer ? I want to understand this :)