# Contact us form with PHPMailer and ReCaptcha V2

Tags: php, phpmailer, recaptcha, php-8

I want to use the below contact us form; I tested it, and I sent emails. There are few issues that I am unable to sort out so that I use the form on a development site. The issues are:

1. When the user hits send an email button while the form is empty, he does not get an alert that the ReCaptcha field is required.
2. If you fill the form and completely ignore the ReCaptcha and hit the send button, you will be taken to a white page, and the email will not be sent. Obviously, this is an error that is not communicated properly to the user.
3. If you fill the form properly and hit send, the thank you page's code does not capture your message. I tried using both `GET` and `Post`. For example: `<?php echo $_POST["name"]?>` and `<?php echo $_GET["name"]?>`.

I use PHP version 8.0.3.
I appreciate it if someone can help me solve these issues.

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test form to email</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class ="container">
<div class="col-lg-6 push-lg-3">
<h1> Contact us</h1>
<p>Fill out the below form to contact us</p>
    <form id= "contactus" method= "post" action= "send.php">
        <input type= "text" name = "name" class = "form-control" placeholder="your Name" required><br />
        <input type= "tel" name = "phone" class = "form-control" placeholder="your Phone" required><br />
        <input type= "email" name = "email" class = "form-control" placeholder="your email address" required><br />
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="your Message" class = "form-control" required></textarea><br />
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="ENTER_YOUR_SITE_KEY_HERE"></div><br />
        <button type= "submit" class = "btn btn-success">Send email</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$("#contactus").validate();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**send.php**

```
<?php
  /**
   * Contact us form for PHPMailer and ReCaptcha V2.
   * Built based on the following resources
   *    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3o0WXaXfUwI
   *    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253428/verify-recaptcha-v2-always-false 
   * This code is not yet final and requires refinement and help from the great community of stackoverflow.com
   */

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php'; //confirm this path
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';      //confirm this path
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php'; //confirm this path

//get the variables from the form 
$name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$phone = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//validations
if(empty($name)){
    header("location:index.php?nouser");
    exit();
}

if(empty($phone)){
    header("location:index.php?nophone");
    exit();
}

if(empty($email)){
    header("location:index.php?noemail");
    exit();
}

if(empty($message)){
    header("location:index.php?nomessage");
    exit();
}


//PHPMailer desfault validations
//Apply some basic validation and filtering to the email
if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST)) {
    $email = substr(strip_tags($_POST['email']), 0, 255);
    } else {
     $email = 'No email';
    }
    
//Apply some basic validation and filtering to the message
if (array_key_exists('message', $_POST)) {
//Limit length and strip HTML tags
    $message = substr(strip_tags($_POST['message']), 0, 16384);
    } else {
    $message = '';
    $msg = 'No message provided!';
    $err = true;
    }
    
//Apply some basic validation and filtering to the name
if (array_key_exists('name', $_POST)) {
//Limit length and strip HTML tags
$name = substr(strip_tags($_POST['name']), 0, 255);
    } else {
    $name = '';
    }

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; //confirm this path

$response   = isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) ? $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] : null;
$privatekey = "ENTER_YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY"; //Enter your secret key here

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'secret' => $privatekey,
    'response' => $response,
    'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
));

$resp = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);

if ($resp->success) {  
  
//Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                               //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                    //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'mail.example.com';             //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                           //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'support@example.com';          //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'PASSWORD';                     //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                          //Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                            //TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Sender
    $mail->setFrom('sender@example.com', 'Mr.sender'); 
    
    //Recipients 
    $mail->addAddress('recipient@example.com', 'Mr. Recipient');  //Add a recipient

    //Body content
    $body = "<p><strong>Hello</strong>, you have received an inquiry from " . $name . " the message is " . $message . " you can contact the sender by phone on " . $phone . " or by email on " . $email . "</p>";
    
    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Website inquiry from ' . $name;
    $mail->email = 'The sender email ' . $email;    
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);

    $mail->send();
    //echo 'Message has been sent'; // select this if you want to echo that the message has been snet
    header("location: thankyou.php"); // Select this if you want to redirect to a thank you page

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

}

?>
```

**thankyou.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Thank you <?php echo $_GET['name'];?> </title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    
</head>

<body>

<div class="container mt-5 text-center">

<body>
    <h1>Thank You <?php echo $_GET['name'];?></h1>
    <p>We have received your inquiry. Here is the information you have submitted:</p>
    <ol>
        <li><em>Name:</em> <?php echo $_GET["name"]?></li>
        <li><em>Email:</em> <?php echo $_GET["email"]?></li>
        <li><em>Phone:</em> <?php echo $_GET["phone"]?></li>
        <li><em>Message:</em> <?php echo $_GET["message"]?></li>
    </ol>   
</body>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `data-sitekey="ENTER_YOUR_SITE_KEY_HERE"` - Did you enter your site key there?

Comment: `header("location: thankyou.php");` You're only redirecting to the page, no `$_GET` parameters whatsoever, so `$_GET["name"]`, `$_GET["phone"]` etc will not be set. Use sessions to store the info before redirecting

Comment: Yes, I did. I was able to send emails, but I miss something in the code when it is else if => when the ReCaptcha is not answered

Comment: `if ($resp->success) { ` You only have code in place for when the captcha-validation was successful, nothing for when it fails

Comment: @brombeer. Exactly! You are with me on the same page. The challenge is that when I use elseif, I get a PHP error.

Comment: Now we can only guess. Why `elseif` and not just a simple `else`? What PHP error do you get then? Please include all relevant code/error messages

Comment: `else` will do the trick! When I place `else {echo "Invalid Captcha, please Try Again";}` before `catch (Exception $e)`, the error is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "else" in file on line 128
Errors parsing file